# Connections not closing

Tags: networking, lan, netstat

I ran netstat and noticed that I have a lot (nearly 100) of connections that are either still `ESTABLISHED` or in `CLOSE_WAIT` state from over a week ago from a different local IP on a different network.

Is there a reason all these connections are hanging?

Answer (score 0):

CLOSE_WAIT means that the peer has closed and TCP is waiting for the local  application to close the connection. You have a bug in your local code, a socket leak.